# Need help for Time calculation based on a calendar in C#

Tags: c#, time

So I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and using a .Net form.  I'm trying to make a clock that will give time in the following format
Years-week of the year-day of the week on 7-hours-minutes-seconds

I'm pretty fine setting the variables for years, hours, minutes and seconds since is a basic thing.  However, I'm not able to find a way to get the week of the year and the days on 7.

So, I've tried for the week of the years calculating it using a simple math 365-DateTime.now.day and dividing by 7.  It's super messy and I got an error log (duh)

I did the same for the days of the week, but using the week formula above as a start.

I know I didn't try much but I'm pretty new to c#.  Its an app I made for learning.  I know the code is missing in the datetime part.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Timer t = new Timer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //timer interval
            t.Interval = 1000; //in milliseconds

            t.Tick += new EventHandler(this.t_tick);

            //start timer when form loads
            t.Start(); //this will use t_tick() method
        }

        //timer interval
        private void t_tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            //get current time
            int yy = DateTime.Now.year;
            int ww = DateTime.Now.//missing code,get the week of the current year??
            int wd = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;  //on 7 days??
            int hh = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            int mm = DateTime.Now.Minute;
            int ss = DateTime.Now.Second;

            //time
            String time = "";

            //padding leading
            if(hh < 10)
            {
                time += "0" + hh;
            }
            else
            {
                time += hh;
            }
            time += ":";

            if (mm < 10)
            {
                time += "0" + mm;
            }

            else
            {
                time += mm;
            }
            time += ":";

            if (ss < 10)
            {
                time += "0" + ss;
            }

            else
            {
                time += ss;
            }

            //update label
            label1.Text = time;






        }

    }
}
```

So, the result expected is simple.  I want to output the date and time as described above.  The actual result is nothing since my code is incomplete.

NOTE: I know I'll need to change the "hh <10" stuff later.  That was a base clock code, to test, if it work the way I thought.

Comment: So what is the question??? Is it the part about Week of Year or Time related?  (Hint: DateTime has the time as time already and you can use ToString to print whatever part(s) thereof you want).  WeekOfYr is more complicated.  Jan 1 was a Tues, does that count as a whole week?  What about of it was Saturday?  is this an ISO WeekOfYear?

Comment: oh sorry yeah im not clear haha i want to output sunday as 1, monday as 2 etc and i want it to output january 1 as week 1. just like the life countdown in the movie "In time" but at the place of a countdown, the current time and i dont know how to get these in code

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjNjqXL4J7iAhUiU98KHehJCMEQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DchUOU0md9A8&psig=AOvVaw3ZFDuhSQ3HehNWzEe-sO_G&ust=1558051573490948

Comment: and to answer to your first question, i want it to be the day of the current week on calendar, mean if the 1 january is a tuesday, its day 1 anyway

Comment: The `visual-studio` tags should only be used when the question is *about* Visual Studio.  Questions about code shouldn't use the VS tags.  [See the tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

The [Calendar class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar?view=netframework-4.8) in System.Globalization should do what you need.

Also, to return a numerical representation of the day of the week you can just cast DayOfWeek to int.

Here's the code you need to fill the two missing variables:

```
        Calendar cal = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar;
        int ww = cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
        int wd = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

Make sure you add a using statement as well:

```
using System.Globalization;
```